# textarea character limit

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, cross-browser

I would like to be able to limit the number of characters in a textarea. The method I am using works great in Google Chrome, but is slow in Firefox, and doesn't work in IE.

Javascript:

```
function len(){
  t_v=textarea.value;
  if(t_v.length>180){
    long_post_container.innerHTML=long_post;
    post_button.className=post_button.className.replace('post_it_regular','post_it_disabled');
    post_button.disabled=true;
  }
  else{
    long_post_container.innerHTML="";
    post_button.className=post_button.className.replace('post_it_disabled','post_it_regular');
    post_button.disabled=false;
  }
  if(t_v.length>186){
        t_v=t_v.substring(0,186);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="user_post_textarea" name="user_post_textarea" cols="28" rows="1"  onkeypress="len();" onkeyup="len();"></textarea>
```

Javascript at bottom of body element:

```
textarea=document.getElementById('user_post_textarea');
```

Comment: And...? How can this question be answered if we can't even see the code?

Comment: update your question with more details please

Comment: Plus, if you don't want people laughing at you, don't put "html5" and "browser compatibility" in the same sentence..

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I found a good solution that uses the [maxlength](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html) attribute if the browser supports it, and falls back to an unobtrusive javascript pollyfill in unsupporting browsers.

Thanks to [@Dan Tello's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit/13576177#comment12927853_5607015) I fixed it up so it works in IE7+ as well:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea maxlength="50" id="text">This textarea has a character limit of 50.</textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function maxLength(el) {    
    if (!('maxLength' in el)) {
        var max = el.attributes.maxLength.value;
        el.onkeypress = function () {
            if (this.value.length >= max) return false;
        };
    }
}

maxLength(document.getElementById("text"));
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ajonol/63/edit)**

There is [no such thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-it-minlength-in-html5) as a `minlength` attribute in HTML5.
For the following input types: `number`, `range`, `date`, `datetime`, `datetime-local`, `month`, `time`, and `week` (which [aren't fully supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)) use the `min` and `max` attributes.

Comment: You edited method seems to be busted in IE 7 + 8. First one seems to work though.

Comment: @DanTello New code with a new demo. Works in IE7+ and other browsers. haven't checked in IE6-.

Comment: Not working in ie "Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected "

Comment: @Nileshpatel I've tested my demo (Here's a [fullscreen version](http://jsbin.com/ajonol/63/quiet) for IE testing) in IE7+ with no errors in the console, and the character limit working properly.

Comment: Problem is: if you run into the limit, it doesn't accept _any_ key press anymore, so you can't even backspace the last sentence. You must use the context menu to delete something.

Comment: I can backspace just fine after hitting the limit in Chrome. What browser are you using? The code uses the `keypress` event not the `keydown` event. Returning false for a `keypress` event shouldn't block control characters like backspace, shift, ctrl, etc.

Comment: You can't press backspace or delete as DanMan mentioned in Firefox if the content is already over limit. In Chrome it works well, but not in FF

Comment: you must first check: if (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.key === "Backspace") {return true;} and then the rest. It will work in FF too

Comment: This won’t prevent pasting a bunch of text, which limits its usefulness.

Answer (score 8):

<strike>This is entirely untested but it should do what you need.</strike>

Update : here's a jsfiddle to look at. Seems to be working. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/BBDJF/1/)

You would past it into a js file and reference it after your jquery reference.
You would then call it like this..

```
$("textarea").characterCounter(200);
```

A brief explanation of what is going on..

On every keyup event the function is checking what type of key is pressed. If it is acceptable the the counter will check the count, trim any excess and prevent any further input once the limit is reached.

The plugin should handle pasting into the target too.

```
  ; (function ($) {
        $.fn.characterCounter = function (limit) {
            return this.filter("textarea, input:text").each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                  checkCharacters = function (event) {

                      if ($this.val().length > limit) {

                          // Trim the string as paste would allow you to make it 
                          // more than the limit.
                          $this.val($this.val().substring(0, limit))
                          // Cancel the original event
                          event.preventDefault();
                          event.stopPropagation();

                      }
                  };

                $this.keyup(function (event) {

                    // Keys "enumeration"
                    var keys = {
                        BACKSPACE: 8,
                        TAB: 9,
                        LEFT: 37,
                        UP: 38,
                        RIGHT: 39,
                        DOWN: 40
                    };

                    // which normalizes keycode and charcode.
                    switch (event.which) {

                        case keys.UP:
                        case keys.DOWN:
                        case keys.LEFT:
                        case keys.RIGHT:
                        case keys.TAB:
                            break;
                        default:
                            checkCharacters(event);
                            break;
                    }   

                });

                // Handle cut/paste.
                $this.bind("paste cut", function (event) {
                    // Delay so that paste value is captured.
                    setTimeout(function () { checkCharacters(event); event = null; }, 150);
                });
            });
        };
    } (jQuery));
```

Comment: In your example then when a key is held down the textarea doesn't trim the number of characters until the key is released. I would like something like @webarto has, but that will filter out [DEL] and [BACKSPACE].

Comment: The example you have allows the placement of another character before it removes this character half a second later but this isn't really what I wanted. I edited the answer @Christian Sciberras provided to filter necessary keycodes and it works great!

Comment: @inquisitive: That could have been fixed easily by changing the line that says if ($this.val().length > limit)  to ($this.val().length >= limit). 

I hope to god you are not writing it in-line like in Christian's example and have at least moved it into a separate js file.

Comment: Start using [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of `keyCode`, `charCode`, or `which` for standards compliance (the latter ones are all deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

using maxlength attribute of textarea would do the trick ... simple html code .. not JS or JQuery or Server Side Check Required....

Comment: Older browsers don't support maxlength. For IE, it must be version 10.

Answer (score 1):

This works on keyup and paste, it colors the text red when you are almost up to the limit, truncates it when you go over and alerts you to edit your text, which you can do.

var t2=   /* textarea reference*/

```
t2.onkeyup= t2.onpaste= function(e){
    e= e || window.event;
    var who= e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(who){
        var val= who.value, L= val.length;
        if(L> 175){
            who.style.color= 'red';
        }
        else who.style.color= ''
        if(L> 180){
            who.value= who.value.substring(0, 175);
            alert('Your message is too long, please shorten it to 180 characters or less');
            who.style.color= '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that doing this might be easier than most people think!

Try this:

```
var yourTextArea = document.getElementById("usertext").value;
// In case you want to limit the number of characters in no less than, say, 10
// or no more than 400.        
    if (yourTextArea.length < 10 || yourTextArea.length > 400) {
        alert("The field must have no less than 10 and no more than 400 characters.");
        return false;
    }
```

Please let me know it this was useful. And if so, vote up! Thx!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you use delegates, it would work..

```
$("textarea").on('change paste keyup', function () {
    var currText = $(this).val();
    if (currText.length > 500) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.substr(0, 500));
        alert("You have reached the maximum length for this field");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery to avoid cross browser compatibility problems...

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).text().length > 500){
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.substr(0, 500));   
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but just to be safe. Anyway he needs to check it on submit and on server side.

Comment: That makes it very slow. Consider that you are move contents on each keypress, even cursor movement.

Comment: all you need to do is .keyup(function(e) { if (>500) { e.preventDefault() });

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty universal jQuery version. Supports copy/paste.

```
$('textarea[maxlength]').on('keypress mouseup', function(){
    return !($(this).val().length >= $(this).attr('maxlength'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have written my method for this, have fun testing it on your browsers, and give me feedback.

cheers.

```
function TextareaControl(textarea,charlimit,charCounter){
    if(
            textarea.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea" && 
            typeof(charlimit)==="number" &&
            typeof(charCounter) === "object" && 
            charCounter.innerHTML !== null
    ){
        var oldValue = textarea.value;
        textarea.addEventListener("keyup",function(){
            var charsLeft = charlimit-parseInt(textarea.value.length,10);
            if(charsLeft<0){
                textarea.value = oldValue;
                charsLeft = charlimit-parseInt(textarea.value.length,10);
            }else{
                oldValue = textarea.value;
            }
            charCounter.innerHTML = charsLeft;
        },false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
... onkeydown="if(value.length>500)value=value.substr(0,500); if(value.length==500)return false;" ...
```

It ought to work.

Comment: It will match exactly 500, what if user pastes text and then continue typing?

Comment: What does returning false do in this instance? Does it not allow additional text to be typed in the textarea?

Comment: Exactly. Returning false aborts the event. In jQuery there's something like "stopPropagation" or something.

Comment: Ok, So I implimented your example but when I reached the character limit (500) it just stopped and I couldn't even back space or delete part of the text.

Comment: Right, you would want to filter out [DEL] and [BACKSPACE]

Comment: There I filtered the necessary navigation keys and edited @Christian Sciberras answer to provide the new code that I have tested In Chrome and IE with excellent results, and Firefox with somewhat choppy results. Anyways at least it works! Thank you everyone for your help :)