# How do I limit a textarea box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone tell me how do I limit a text area to certain characters only? Let's say 250.

```js
function handle(){
  let element = document.getElementById('input')
  let value = element.value
  let maxLength = element.maxLength
  document.getElementById('remaining').innerText = `${maxLength - Number(value.length)} characters remaining`
  
}
```

```html
<textarea col="8" rows="8" maxlength='250' onkeyup="handle()" id="input" value="">Hello World. Im born today.</textarea>
<p id='remaining'>250 characters remaining</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit

Answer (score 1):

You can use maxlength attribute of [**textarea**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

> The maximum number of characters (unicode code points) that the user
>   can enter. If this value isn't specified, the user can enter an
>   unlimited number of characters.

```html
<textarea col="8" rows="8" maxlength='5'></textarea>
```

> And what if I want to show how many characters remaining? Like how I'm
>   seeing in the comments I'm writing?

```js
function handle(){
  let element = document.getElementById('input')
  let value = element.value
  let maxLength = element.maxLength
  document.getElementById('remaining').innerText = `Remaining charcaters   ${maxLength - Number(value.length)}`
  
}
```

```html
<textarea col="8" rows="8" maxlength='250' onkeyup="handle()" id='input' value=''></textarea>
<p id='remaining'></p>
```

Comment: And what if I want to show how many characters remaining? Like how I'm seeing in the comments I'm writing?

Comment: Subtract the text area's value.length from the maxLength value.

Comment: @DrewReese Any example?

Comment: @BillNathan you can subtract value from maxlength, you can check update answer

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks Code! Lastly, how do I keep showing 250 characters remaining by default and it starts to reduce then? :)

Comment: @BillNathan you can add a initial value in `p` tag and than the same as above example

Comment: @CodeManiac This is awesome. I have updated my code too, and it works smooth! I hope you can help me with the last inter-linked query. What if at 100 words I want to turn the text yellow and on 0 words red. So I can notify user you're nearly reaching the word count, and then you've reached the limit.

Comment: @BillNathan in the same function where we are adding innerText to p tag, you can update style based on the remaining characters

Comment: I guess I can do one style but how about three styles? Black, yellow, red? Any example?

Comment: @BillNathan you need not to do anything for `black` as it is default, and you will be having only one color at a time so based on remaining characters you can use `if else` condition to add style, try once if you still found it difficult let me

Comment: @CodeManiac I found one more issue in this. If the value is preset it doesn't count the remaining words. See my example.